# Batch File To Read

Tags: string, file, batch-file, variables

Can someone help me?
I needed a BAT that read my TXT file containing the information:

```
File.txt
======================
SAGEM BETA PORT (COM1)
SAGEM TELIUM COMM PORT (COM2)
MAGIC COMM (COM1)
======================
```

And I would always find the device "SAGEM TELIUM COMM PORT" that will be in the file and inform me of a variable which COM is connected to (Ex: COM2).
 It's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a file in a batch file you can use the `FOR /F` command. But in your instance you also need to find a specific line within the input file.  Luckily the `FOR /F` command can also parse the output of console commands as well.  So you can use the `FIND` command with your search string to find the correct line.  The `FOR /F` command allows you split up a line by defining delimiters.  In this case it will be the parentheses.  In your example you would want the `FOR /f` command to grab the 2nd delimited part of your data.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%G IN ('find "SAGEM TELIUM COMM PORT" file.txt') do echo %%G
```

Comment: thanks a lot squashman
but I create a file with name "File.txt" and with values:
OTHER DEVICE (COM3)
SAGEM TELIUM COMM PORT (COM2)
OTHER DEVICE (COM1)

But when a I run the script:
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=()" %%G IN ('find "SAGEM TELIUM COMM PORT" file.txt') do echo %%G

The result is nothing.
The BAT and the TXT file are in the same location (C: \)

Comment: Should be `tokens=2` your posting of the file was misleading, I corrected this; view your question in edit mode to see the changes.

Comment: @ChristianRibeiro, please read, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)